# is_tarfile() returns True for a blank file

Tags: python

**EDIT 1**

Hmm, I accept the answers that tar respects an empty file... but on my system:

```
$ touch emptytar
$ tar -tf emptytar 
tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Maybe I have a non-canonical version?

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.22
Copyright (C) 2009 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>.
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.

Written by John Gilmore and Jay Fenlason.
```

Hello all,

I am testing some logic to handle a user uploading a TAR file.  When I feed a blank file to `tarfile.is_tarfile()` it returns `True`, which is not what I am expecting:

```
$ touch tartest
$ cat tartest
$ python -c "import tarfile; print tarfile.is_tarfile('tartest')"
True
```

If I add some text to the file, it returns `False`, which I am expecting:

```
$ echo "not a tar" > tartest
$ python -c "import tarfile; print tarfile.is_tarfile('tartest')"
False
```

I could add a check at the beginning to check for a zero-length file, but based on the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.is_tarfile) for `tarfile.is_tarfile(name)` I think this is unecessary:

> Return True if name is a tar archive
>   file, that the tarfile module can
>   read.

I went so far as to check the source, [tarfile.py](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Lib/tarfile.py), and I can see that it is checking header blocks but I do not fully understand how it is evaluating those blocks.

Am I misreading the documentation and therefore setting unfair expectations?

Thank you,
Zachary

Comment: The `tar` I've tried with is GNU's 1.15.1 (as ported by Apple to MacOSX/Darwin); I'm at a loss to explain your observation that 1.22 seems to have changed in a backwards incompatible way!

Comment: I can confirm the error behaviour of GNU tar 1.26 on an empty file: it throws an error whereas tarfile.is_tarfile returns True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this at the command line:

```
$ touch emptyfile
$ tar -tvf emptyfile
```

No errors.

It looks like an empty file simply is a valid (but useless) TAR file.

Answer (score 4):

An empty tar file **is** a perfectly valid, and empty, tar file.  Consider, at any Unix shell prompt:

```
$ touch foo.tar
$ ls -l foo.tar
-rw-r--r--  1 aleax  staff  0 Jun 16 18:49 foo.tar
$ tar tvf foo.tar 
$ tar xvf foo.tar
```

See?  The empty `foo.tar` is a perfectly valid tar file for the Unix `tar` command -- it just has nothing to show or to unpack.  It would be truly problematic if Python's tar handling differed so drastically from that of `tar` itself!  What sentence in the docs led you to believe that such a problematic, headache-inducing incompatibility is part of the specs?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, the behaviour of "is_tarfile" seems to have changed between Python 2.6 and 2.7.  In Python 2.7, `is_tarfile` returns `False` for an empty file.

```
$ touch /tmp/foo.tar
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jul 24 2012, 11:41:40) 
[GCC 4.6.3 20120306 (Red Hat 4.6.3-2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tarfile
>>> print tarfile.is_tarfile("/tmp/foo.tar")
False
>>> 
$
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score -1):

This is a fundamental feature of logic.

The default assumption is "True" until proven false by the contents of the file.

No contents, no disproof of the assumption.

Comment: So why does python's zipfile.is_zipfile(emptyfile) does return False?